# Using sync modifier between Parent and Grandchildren Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

**Problem**

Let's say I have a vue component called:

*Note: All vue components has been simplified to explain what I'm trying to do.*

reusable-comp.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input type="text" :value.number="setValue" class="form-control" @input="$emit('update:setValue', $event.target.value)">
        <span>
            <button @click="incrementCounter()" :disabled="disabled" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-bordercolor btn-number" data-type="plus">
                <i class="fa fa-plus gray7"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

    export default {
        props: {
            setValue: {
                type: Number,
                required: false,
                default: 0
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            incrementCounter: function () {
                this.setValue += 1;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then in a parent component I do something like this:

subform.vue

```
<div class="row mb-1">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Increment Value of Num A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <reuseable-comp :setValue.sync="numA"></reuseable-comp>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    import reusableComp from '../reusable-comp'
    export default {
        components: {
            reusableComp 
        },
        props: {
            numA: {
                type: Number,
                required: false,
                default: 0
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {

        }
    }
</script>
```

then lastly

page_layout.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <subform :numA.sync="data1" />
   </div>
 </template>
 <script>
     import subform from '../subform.vue'
     export default {
         components: {
             subform
     },
     data() {
        return {
            data1: 0
        }
    }
 }
</script>
```

**Question**

So, how do I sync a value between reusable-comp.vue, subform.vue, and page_layout.vue

I'm using reuseable-comp.vue is many different places. I'm using subform.vue only a couple times in page_layout.vue

And I'm trying to use this pattern several times. But I can't seem to get this to work. The above gives me an error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "numA"

Comment: you could pass a method from `page_layout.vue` down to your children. that method would mutate `data1` on top level and re-render all children.

imo, generally it's a bad pattern, don't try to mutate props, mutate only data from the component :D

Comment: doesn't the data bubble up from the reusable-comp.vue component? meaning what i change there, would have to be changed on the grandparent. im. saying this because the reusable-comp.vue can also be found else where outside this heirarchy. it doesnt make sense to put general logic on an abstract component.

Comment: This is stylistic, but could you reverse the order of that you present the components in? Going from the leaf component back up to the root component is mind boggling since I naturally want to scroll down from most general to most specific.

Comment: What do you mean? im bubbling upwards. The page layout is keeping track of the data model, the child components need to update that data model. The page layout is compiling all information so that it will be sent to the server when finished. This can be accomplished when you have a parent to child relationship and using the sync modifier.. but it gets more complex when you work with grandchildren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found a solution that worked.

In subform.vue, we change:

```
    data() {
        return {
            numA_data : this.numA
        }
    }
```

So we now have reactive data to work with. Then in the template, we refer to that reactive data instead of the prop:

```
<reuseable-comp :setValue.sync="numA_data"></reuseable-comp>
```

Then finally we add a watcher to check if the reactive data gets changed, and then emit to the parent:

```
watch: {
    numA_data: function(val) {
         this.$emit('update:numA', this.numA_data);
    }
}
```

Now all values from grandchildren to parent are synced.

---

**Update (4/13/2018)**

I made new changes to the reusable-comp.vue:

- I replaced where it says 'setValue' to 'value'
- I replaced where it says 'update:value' to 'input'

Everything else says the same.

Then in subform.vue:

- I replaced ':setValue.sync' to 'v-model'

v-model is two way binding, so I made use of that where it needed to be. The sync between the parent-child (not child to grandchild), is still using sync modifier, only because the parent has many props to pass. I could modify this where I could group up the props as a single object, and just pass that.

Comment: You should use a computed property instead of data , so if the prop won't change, vuejs won't recalculate and render numA_data.

Comment: Oh and if you wanted to keep that design even if it isn't the right one, don't forget that in javascript objects and arrays are passed by reference, so for example you can have a big object that keeps all of the properties that you want to pass down.  :myObject="myObject", if you change in a child component myObject.numA, it will change the parent's myObject and it won't give an error.  But again, it isn't a good idea, just a workaround

Comment: Another thing is that , emit and broadcast will work just fine for small apps but if you plan to get more complex than the example, probably you will need vuex store.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. You make really good points. The prop data does change in the subform, because the inputs are coming in from the parent control (page_layout.vue), not from this form. Because of that, it HAS to recalculate the numA_data. if you don't agree, you can post an answer explaining what you mean, and I can test it out.

Comment: Also, I thought about using vuex, and I already use it in certain cases, but for this kind of coupled dependency it's really not needed. Looking at all three components, it's explicitly showing that its tightly coupled, with all the logic defined within the component itself. I prefer using vuex more for sibling relationships or loosely coupled dependencies, as it's makes sense out of the complex component-component communication.

Comment: Solution passing value through [computed value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70278325/3548833)